# IntelliJ IDEA 15 Ultimate, Other Settings missing from Settings window

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle, intellij-15

I recently upgraded from `IntelliJ 14` to `15 ultimate` and I realized I can no longer configure `checkstyles` as `Other Settings` in setting window is completely missing.

I cannot understand what I did wrong, and I am not sure if it's some configuration missing to get this `Other Settings` back.

Exact version : IntelliJ Ultimate 15.0.1

Here is how it looks:
[image]
[image]

What I tried:
Well I tried searching if there is a way to bring it back, but no luck yet. my colleague is using same version and he can see it. So may be during importing some settings or default configuration from IntelliJ 14, something went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened on an EAP build of Intellij 15:

#### Solution 1

[image]

I had the same issue after upgrade. For me the fix was simply to uninstall Checkstyle-IDEA, restart Intellij and then install it again after which I was able to see: Refer here for doing the same : [IntelliJ Installing Plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html)

[image]

#### Solution 2

If a restart does not fix your problem, I would recommend a manual cleanup. Steps to do so:

1. Uninstall Checkstyle-IDEA plugin from within Intellij
2. Close Intellij and remove the Checkstyle-IDEA directory from the plugins folder.  The location of the plugins folder depends on the OS and is documented here : https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181 
    For example:
    Windows: `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\config\plugins` 
    OSX: `~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdeaXX`
3. Re-install the plugin and (after a restart) check if you can see the 'Other Settings' -> 'Checkstyle' section again.

---

#### Suggestion

Also, I am tempted to suggest that it might be worth seeing if the 'Other Settings' section appears when you install a plugin like 'Grep Console' which puts it's settings there:

[image]

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me, I didn't had to uninstall the plugin as I guess it was missing. Just installed it. Thank you